# C++: Execute function when program terminates

Tags: c++, console, signals, atexit

Some programs pop "Save before exit?" message when terminating.
And I wonder if I can implement this with C++ console application.
So I tried some standard functions like `signal` and `atexit`.

But they only work when:

- `main()` returns (`atexit`)
- sending interrupt through Ctrl+C (on Windows, `SIGINT`)
- an error occurs (`SIGABRT`)

So yeah, how? Is it only possible with GUI application?

Comment: Note that GUI applications achieve this because they are handling a _request_ to exit, not the actual exit.  If you similarly design your program around this style of message processing, there's no reason you can't do the same thing.  As for your question, it's unclear what the actual problem is.  You've said you're handling lower-level exit events and listed cases where it works for you, but you have not specified cases that _don't_ work (_i.e._ the actual problem you're trying to solve)

Comment: I want exit events to happen when that 'X' button is pressed(On windows).
That's part of GUI I guess. 
Than what kind of request is sent to program when the exit button of the console is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, you said:

> I want exit events to happen when that 'X' button is pressed(On windows).
>   That's part of GUI I guess. 
>   Than what kind of request is sent to program when the exit button of the console is pressed?

You can use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) to register a [user defined callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) that receives a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` notification when the console window is closed:

> A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console (either by clicking **Close** on the console window's window menu, or by clicking the **End Task** button command from Task Manager).